# Select rows where the title contains any term from a list

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a datset that has product_id, product_url, email, product_title, etc.

I want to pull rows where product_title contains certain adjectives (Fabulous, Stunning, Rare, Amazing, Unique, etc etc. ) from a list of 400+ words.

How do I do this without doing a separate select function for each word? I am using SQLite

Comment: `select * from dataset d where exists (select null from ref_ds rd where d.property like '%' || rd.term || '%')`

Comment: @astentx Please turn that into an explained answer.

Comment: @astentx what do the Pipe chars do in your query?

Comment: @MichaelZ. Pipes are for concatenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a single query using `or`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.title like '%Fabulous%' or
      t.title like '%Stunning%' or
      . . .  ;
```

If the words are stored in a separate table, you could use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from interesting_words iw
              where t.title like '%' || iw.word || '%'
             );
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! I learned a bunch from using this. Took a bit of trouble shooting but thanks for helping me on the job.